# Trying to use newly installed Visual Studio for debugging, but get this error on my browser window

Tags: visual-studio, vscode-debugger

[image]

this is the error I get:

This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.

Try:

- Checking the connection
- Checking the proxy and the firewall
- ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Do you have an an application your are trying to run? Visual Studio doesn't just "make localhost work". The issue could be the application. To get started, create a new project, and then click "Play" :) (start debugging). To help you on your StackOverflow journey, you need to provide a lot more details. Is IIS Express running for example?

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Thank you for your help.